# function returns undefined in console

Tags: javascript, html, function, console.log

I have a function with a parameter of string. I was expecting to get `reff` in the console, but for some reason I'm getting `undefined`. Here is my code:

```js
var _ref;
function foo(_ref='reff') {
  var bar = _ref.bar;
  return console.log(bar);
}
foo (_ref)
```

Why does this log `undefined` instead of `reff`?

Comment: "_I should be getting 'reff' in console_" Why ..? How ..? You're assigning a non-existing property of `_ref` to `bar`, its value is `undefined`.

Comment: what is the purpose for this line `var bar = _ref.bar;`? why not `console.log(_ref)`?

Comment: default value is a string, and you reference. property bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting undefined because you are returning `console.log` from `foo` and even if you fixed your function the console.log will still spit out undefined because `_ref` is a string and not an object with a bar property.

so you call `foo` with `_ref`, which is undefined at the moment and when the function foo runs it will set it to the string `'reff'` which doesn't have a bar property, therefore logging undefined.

so you have the undefined from both scenarios

Comment: my guess is, someone thought you didn't put reasonable effort before posting. anyways accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

ok I'll explain your code line by line for you to understand how it runs:

```
// you define a variable name _ref, its default value is `undefined`
var _ref; 

// you define a function name `foo`
// the function has one argument name `_ref` (different with the first _ref)
// this argument has a default value = 'reff'
function foo(_ref = 'reff') { // since you called `foo` with undefined value, _ref will get its default value 'reff'
  var bar = _ref.bar; // _ref is a string, so _ref.bar is undefined => bar is undefine
  return console.log(bar); // log undefined
}

// you call the function `foo` with `_ref` (it is `undefined`) 
foo(_ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var _ref;
function foo(_ref='reff') {

  var bar = _ref;
return   console.log( bar);
}
foo (_ref)
```

please sir what is the use of the appended (.bar) property